# How to stream large json object to browser in ASP.Net Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core, stream

When stream large json object to browser, to prevent **OutOfMemoryException**; in .Net Framework, I was able to use

```
public static void StreamJsonThenEnd(this HttpResponseBase httpResponse, object data)
{
    httpResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(httpResponse.OutputStream))
    using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
    {
        JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
        ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, data);
        jsonWriter.Flush();
    }
    httpResponse.End();
}
```

But when I worked on .Net Core, I tried below code but it gave me *Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead*

```
public static void StreamJsonThenEnd(this HttpResponse httpResponse, object data)
{
    httpResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpResponse.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(httpResponse.Body))
    using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
    {
        JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
        ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, data);
        jsonWriter.Flush();
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
public static async Task StreamJsonThenEnd(this HttpResponse httpResponse, object data)
{
    httpResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpResponse.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
    await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(httpResponse.Body, data, data.GetType());
}
```

but it now throw *The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started*

How can I stream my json object in ASP.Net Core?

Comment: If the data is splittable, you can try to send multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like Json is not actually root cause of my problem, as in .Net Core it already used stream for json by default [JsonResultExecutor](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/195a22d92c95445fabef3b17e67bee4aa75eff81/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonResultExecutor.cs)